# how to install cruise control (Tempomat) in an Mercedes-Benz 308D from 1992?

Tags: retrofit, mercedes-benz, cruise-control

I would like to retrofit a Mercedes-Benz 308D van from year 1992 (model number 602.316) with cruise control.

What parts would I need to buy and how to proceed installing them?

I mostly see parts for sale for passenger models, for example W115, W123 - would these be compatible?

Comment: BTW, could someone with enough reputation add these tags: mercedes tempomat mercedes-benz cruise-control

Comment: someone's already gotten to the tags for you, but with tempomat since it appears to be the German work for cruise-control I created a tag synonym and so whenever `tempomat` is used, it will be tied to `cruise-control`

Comment: @Patrick if you are at it, `mercedes` tag as a synonym for `mercedes-benz` might be useful - in case someone searches for tag mercedes alone, or just to prevent it being added as a standalone tag.

Comment: @Troggy why did you change the "mercedes-benz" tag to "mercedes" which is a synonym, but now this question is not visible under [tag mercedes-benz](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mercedes-benz) Can you change the tag back to mercedes-benz?

Comment: @Patrick you created the synonym, but now "mercedes-benz" is gone from the list of valid tags, so can you add it back?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but for BMW Z3s they made a kit that allowed for you to just basically plug it in. I installed one once, and remember the kit costing like a couple of hundred bucks. I recommend going to dealership, get estimate, and then see if it has a part number you can cross reference for the kit to see if there are cheaper options online, or just buy the dealers kit.